# FAB as Android lock ring

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I would like to have a Floating Action Button (FAB) that when clicked would expand and display more options, which could be navigated by draging your finger, like with the android lock ring.

I have found some libraries that replicate the lock ring, but they are not what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to implement this behaviour with a FAB?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with hiding and showing FAB programmatically

```
@OnClick(R.id.expand)
public void onExpand(View view) {
    Utils.hideKeyboard(this);

    if (isFabOpen) {
      expand.startAnimation(rotateBackward);
      facebook.startAnimation(fabClose);
      twitter.startAnimation(fabClose);
      signUp.startAnimation(fabClose);
    } else {
      expand.startAnimation(rotateForward);
      facebook.startAnimation(fabOpen);
      twitter.startAnimation(fabOpen);
      signUp.startAnimation(fabOpen);
    }

    isFabOpen = !isFabOpen;
    facebook.setClickable(isFabOpen);
    twitter.setClickable(isFabOpen);
    signUp.setClickable(isFabOpen);
}
```

Comment: I understand that this would allow me to show new options when the fab is clicked. However, I still think it requires a second touch to select the options, and not just sliding over it, like with the lock ring.